# How to compare fields from different tables

Tags: mysql, join, field, conditional-statements

I want to select rows from a table (products), but that table is linked to another one (stock) using JOIN statement.

In products table there are 2 important fields, SKU and minimum_stock.
In stock table there are SKU (relation with products) and qty

Now, I want to select rows from products only if in table stock exists SKU, and qty is > minimum_stock from products.

Like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products
INNER JOIN stock ON products.SKU = stock.SKU
WHERE products.minimum_stock.value > stock.qty.value;
```

Obviously this code not works.

Can somebody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `products.minimum_stock.value` is going to be interepreted as database `products`, table `minimum_stock`, field `value`. since you're selecting from `productos` and `stock`, you're using tables/fields which don't exist.

Comment: what is .value here? remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your tables look like:

**products:**

- SKU
- minimum_stock
- (... other columns ...)

**stock**

- SKU
- qty
- (... other columns ...)

Your query doesn't have to have the .value at the end of the columns. In fact, that's what would make this not work.

Do something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products
INNER JOIN stock ON products.SKU = stock.SKU
WHERE products.minimum_stock > stock.qty;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4bd43/1)</kbd>

Comment: Well I thought it would be more complicated, thanks a lot, right now my code works.

Comment: @Alan. Great. If you feel like this answer helped, consider [accepting it as correct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)